# Rails ActionCable identify by the link parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I don't need a User login in my website because i want to use a link parameter, in this way:

Link: [www.website.com/link/2yM5KP6Vj6E3XdWS](http://www.website.com/link/2yM5KP6Vj6E3XdWS)

***/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb***

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        cookies[:link_param] = params[:link]
    end
end
```

***/app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb***

```
module ApplicationCable
    class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
        identified_by :current_user
        
        def connect
            self.current_user = Link.find_by(token: cookies[:link_param])
        end
    end
end
```

But i don't want to use `cookies` for this, because it only expired when you close the browser and i want something like [`flash`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm) works but i can't use flash in `ApplicationCable::Connection` class.

> A flash stores a value (normally text) until the next request

I'm doing this because i need to interact depending of link you enter and don't care how many user enter it. I don't want that ActionCable continue sending data because cookies[:link_param] is available.

Is there a way to do this or should i force to login system or use `cookies.delete :link_param` in all actions of all controllers i have.

**Edit:**
Maybe this is an option from client side:

***/app/assets/javascripts/channels/info.coffee***

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "InfoChannel", link_param: "#{link_param}" },
    connected: ->

    disconnected: ->

    received: ->
```

Letting the customer say what link is.

Comment: Without using cookies or user auth system, it looks a not possible thing..

Comment: I'm using the client side option and it's running very nice, but i want to know if someone knows a way to solve this from server side or if someone find a bug in client side option.